# Mouse keys randomly turning on

Tags: windows-10, mouse-keys

So a few months back I started having mouse keys randomly turn on. I can turn it off but they will randomly turn back on later. (I assume its not random but I use 10 key just rarely enough that I have no clue what does it.

It also gets turned on under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Change sign-in settings

Not sure if this is a symptom or part of the cause but this gets replicated across from my laptop to a desktop
i built after all this started signed into the same microsoft account.

I will turn it off and a few days later it will be back on.
Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Could you have hit the keyboard shortcut, left Alt + left Shift + Num Lock, by accident?

Comment: No. Just tried it and it appears that shortcut is disabled.